# Can't request bluetooth premission on android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, permission-denied

Hello I've been struggling with requesting the following bluetooth permissions on Android Studio: BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, BLUETOOTH_SCAN, BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE but none of them wants to be requested: I'm using the following code to request BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final int BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION_CODE = 4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonRequest = findViewById(R.id.button);
    buttonRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have already granted this permission!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                requestStoragePermission();
            }
        }
    });

}



@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
private void requestStoragePermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN)) {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Permission needed")
                .setMessage("This permission is needed because of this and that")
                .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN}, BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION_CODE);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .create().show();

    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN}, BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission DENIED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

And there is also a manifest file which contains the following content:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"/>
```

unfortunately this code doesn't work. It always shows permission denied. It doesn't even display dialog ***But if I want to request for example READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE premision it works without any problems*** could you tell me guys why is this happening? Can't bluetooth permissions be requested by the way from above? Best wishes and waiting for help!